# Going back to SpriteBatch.Draw() after using GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives()

Tags: c#, xna, spritebatch

In my 2D XNA game, I've been trying to draw triangles. I've been following the tutorial [here](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/The_first_triangle.php).

```
// Game1.FX is a static instance of Effect
Game1.FX.CurrentTechnique = Game1.FX.Techniques["Pretransformed"];

foreach (EffectPass pass in Game1.FX.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();

    Game1.GameInstance.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, 1, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
}

// Exception is thrown when we go back to spriteBatch.Draw()
spriteBatch.Draw(Textures.Get("Projectiles\\laser01"), new Rectangle((int)compartment.Position.X, (int)compartment.Position.Y,
    compartment.CompartmentWeapon.MaxRange, 2), null, laserColour, gunRotation - compartment.CompartmentWeapon.ArcLOS, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
```

I receive a System.InvalidOperationException when going back to the spriteBatch.Draw() from the GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives().

"A valid vertex buffer (and a valid index buffer if you are using indexed primitives) must be set on the device before any draw operations may be performed."

I would be grateful if anyone could point out why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `spriteBatch.End()` before your `DrawUserPrimitives()`.  Then before you try to issue another `spriteBatch.Draw()`, you must issue another `spriteBatch.Begin()`.

`SpriteBatch.Begin()` sets up all of the buffers and staging for you in order to provide easy rendering functionality.  As soon as you touch `GraphicsDevice` you risk making changes to things that the `SpriteBatch` may not be aware of, and restarting the SpriteBatch helps reset the pipeline to a known state.

Doing things on GraphicsDevice like changing the current RenderTarget or clearing a target are fine.